# Web приложение базы знаний

Tags: java, веб-программирование, jsp

Все привет! Мне нужно написать веб приложение, где при открытии стартовой страницы, оно бы сканировало заданную папку и на ее основе создавало бы структурное дерево со ссылками на файлы в формате .doc. 
Я создал класс Folder:

```
public class Folder {
    private String name;
    private String path;
    private File file;
    private ArrayList<Folder> folders = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<>();

    public Folder(File file) {
        this.file = file;
        name = file.getName();
        path = file.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    public File[] getListFiles(){
        return file.listFiles();
    }

    public void setFolders(Folder folder){
        folders.add(folder);
    }

    public void setFiles(File file){
        files.add(file);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public ArrayList<Folder> getFolders() {
        return folders;
    }

    public ArrayList<File> getFiles() {
        return files;
    }
}
```

Есть обработчик, с методом parseFolder, который сканирует папку:

```
    public class Executor {

    private Folder folder = new Folder(new File("Z:\\Справочник"));
    StringBuffer html = new StringBuffer();
    private int i = 0;

    public Folder getFolder() {
        return folder;
    }


    public void parseFolder(Folder folder){
        File[] tmp = folder.getListFiles();
        for (File f : tmp){
            if (f.isDirectory()){
                Folder folderTmp = new Folder(f);
                folder.setFolders(folderTmp);
                parseFolder(folderTmp);

            }else if (f.isFile()){
                folder.setFiles(f);
            }
        }
    }

    public void printHtml(Folder folder) {
        if (folder.getFolders().size() != 0) {
            for (Folder fO : folder.getFolders()) {
                html.append("<ul>").append(fO.getName());
                html.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                printHtml(fO);
            }
        }
        if (folder.getFiles().size() != 0) {
            for (File fS : folder.getFiles()) {
                if (fS.getName().equals("Thumbs.db"))
                    continue;
                html.append("<li><a href=\"").append(fS.getAbsolutePath()).append("\">").append(fS.getName()).append("</a></li>");
                html.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
        }
        html.append("</ul>");
        html.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }

    public String getHtml() {
        return html.toString();
    }
}
```

JSP страница:

```
<%@ page import="com.vcto.kuprijanov.Executor" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>База знаний</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
 </head>

<body>
    <%
        Executor ex = new Executor();
        ex.parseFolder(ex.getFolder());
        ex.printHtml(ex.getFolder());
    %>
   <%= ex.getHtml()%>
</body>
</html>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как теперь корректно вывести структуру со ссылками на JSP страницу.

Comment: Добавьте пример вашей JSP страницы, и укажите что не получается сделать.

Comment: Добавил. Посмотрите, как работает метод displayStructure, онв консоль выводит структуру просканированной папки. Мне нужно вывести ту же информацию только на web страницу, чтобы пользователь мог просмотреть всю структуру по разделам и открыть определенные файлы по ссылкам

Comment: Измените метод `void printHtml` на `String printHtml`, где будете возвращать сгенерированный хтмл, и все должно работать. Если не хочет работать, попробуйте добавить `<%= ex.printHtml(ex.getFolder())%>`  после вашего скриплета.

Comment: Подредактировал, теперь получаю String на jsp странице, но страница по прежнему пустая, ничего не отображается

Comment: В самом скриплете уберите `ex.getHtml();`, а после скриплета вставьте `<%= ex.getHtml()%>`

Comment: Oleg1n, решил попробовать проверить результат. Создал папку musor в нее закинул несколько *.doc. Соответственно сменил путь к папке. В результате на JSP - одни точки :-) кол-во точек соответствует кол-ву файлов... В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: в классе Executor в строчке html.append("<li><a href=\"").append(fS.getAbsolutePath()).append("\">").append(fS.getName()).append("</a></li>"); была ошибка, проверьте, может быть это повлияло на отображение